# How to convert cq user profie image to base64 encoded string

Tags: java, base64, aem, jcr

I uploded profile pic through granite operations. If we upload profile pic here, it is adding the jcr.data property as binary data under /image/jcr:content
ex: /home/users/s/sampleuser/profile/photos/primary/image/jcr:content
[image]

I am trying to convert this binary data using org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 but it is not returning the correct encoded string.

Code which I am trying:

```
Node photoNode = node.getNode("photos/primary/image/jcr:content");
javax.jcr.Binary binaryData = photoNode.getProperty("jcr:data").getBinary();
InputStream input = binaryData.getStream();
int BUFF_SIZE=1024;
byte[] line=new byte[BUFF_SIZE];
ByteArrayOutputStream output=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while (input.read(line) != -1) {
output.write(line);
}
Base64 base64=new Base64();
byte[] encoded=base64.encode(output.toByteArray());
String enodedString = Base64.encodeBase64String(encoded);
LOG.info("is Base64::"+Base64.isBase64(enodedString));
LOG.info("enodedString"+enodedString);
photo = enodedString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = binaryData.getStream();
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
    String base64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
}
catch (IOException e) {
}
finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(is)
}
```

IOUtils from apache-io is your friend here. Not sure what is wrong with your code as it looks ok, though a bit cumbersome with the buffer.